# Gvis graph won't render Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

R/Shiny newbie here, I seem to be having some trouble generating a simple line chart.

I am trying to be able to display each graph by user input, however I can't seem to get a simple line chart working.

```
head(futures_data)

                   Corn        Wheat     Soybeans
2001-01-02 -0.019417476 -0.011627907 -0.009009009
2001-01-03  0.012101210  0.025339367  0.004545455
2001-01-04  0.000000000  0.003530450 -0.010055304
2001-01-05 -0.017391304 -0.004397537 -0.005586592
2001-01-08 -0.001106195  0.000000000  0.003064351
2001-01-09  0.007751938  0.007067138  0.008655804
```

rownames(futures_data) gives the dates for each row of data.

```
server.R

library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

server <- function(input, output){

    futures <- as.data.frame(futures_data)
    fut <- cbind.data.frame(x=futures$Corn, y=rownames(futures))

    output$abc <- renderText({ "sjdaflkjsd" })
    output$g1 <- renderPlot({
        gvisLineChart(
                      data=fut
                      ,xvar="x"
                      ,yvar="y" 
        )
    })
    output$t1 <- renderTable({ head(futures) }) 
}
```

when using `output$g1 <- renderGvis({})` the table disappears as well.

```
ui.R

    library(shiny)
    library(googleVis)

    ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("ShinyProj")
   ,sidebarLayout(
               mainPanel(

                          ,plotOutput("g1")
                          ,tableOutput("t1")
                          )
               ,sidebarPanel(
                            radioButtons("typeInput"
                                          ,"Product Type"
                                          ,choices=c("Corn","Wheat","Soybeans")
                                          ,selected=("Corn")
                            )
        ) 

)
```

My question is what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance and any other criticism very welcome

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the appropriate `render` and `Output` functions:

#### ui.R

```
htmlOutput("g1")
```

#### server.R

```
output$g1 <- renderGvis({
  gvisLineChart(
    data = fut,
    xvar = "x",
    yvar = "y" 
  )
})
```

Then a known issue is that your output won't show in the RStudio browser, run your app and open it in a classical browser (Firefox, Chrome...).

There might also be a problem when plotting your data with dates on the y-axis. But it works well when dates are laid on the x-axis.